# how to resolve the async await issue in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise

The following is my code

```js
let icsFileData = [];
icsFileData = filterAttachmentArray.map(async(file) => {
  let buff = new Buffer(file.data, 'base64');
  let text = buff.toString('ascii');
  const data = await ical.async.parseICS(text);
  const objectKeys = Object.values(data);
  const filterObj =
    objectKeys.length === 1 || objectKeys[0].type === 'VEVENT' ? objectKeys[0] : objectKeys[1];
  const desiredObj = {
    subject: filterObj.summary.val ? filterObj.summary.val : filterObj.summary,
    description: filterObj.description.val ? filterObj.description.val : filterObj.description,
    dateStart: moment(filterObj.start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss\\Z'),
    dateEnd: moment(filterObj.end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss\\Z'),
    organizer: filterObj.organizer.params.EMAIL ?
      filterObj.organizer.params.EMAIL :
      filterObj.organizer.val.split('mailto:').join(''),
    invites: filterObj.attendee.length === undefined ?
      filterObj.attendee.params.EMAIL ?
      filterObj.attendee.params.EMAIL :
      filterObj.attendee.val.split('mailto:').join('') :
      filterObj.attendee.map(
        (invite) =>
        invite.params.EMAIL ? invite.params.EMAIL : invite.val.split('mailto:').join('')
      ),
    location: filterObj.location.val ? filterObj.location.val : filterObj.location
  };
  icsFileData.push(desiredObj);
});
//const icsFileDataArray = await Promise.all(icsFileData);
console.log('jhgjhgjhgj: ', await icsFileData);
```

Please check what is the issue, I tried many times always get the same
result.

Here is the result this code always returns me

```
[ Promise { <pending> } ]
```

Comment: can you add a snippet of your code, that's better than a picture, also would help addressing your issue.

Comment: i have add please check

Comment: ``Promise{}`` means that you have to use **.then()** to check the value.  Use something like this ``const returnFromAwait = await icsFileData();`` then try ``returnFromAwait.then(res => console.log(res));``

Comment: not working i tried this one

Comment: Promise {<resolved>: undefined}                                                                                          
__proto__: Promise                                                                             
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"                                                                                  Getting something like this?
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined

Answer (score 2):

Things to understand,

1. `async/await` are just a syntactical sugar to write async code in
   synchronous fashion
2. the callback inside your `.map(async() => { ...})` gonna return a `Promise`.
3. so in your code, `icsFileData` is a collection of
   `Promise`, so you have to use `Promise.all` to resolve all the
   promises to get the desired result

```
let icsFileData = [];
icsFileData = filterAttachmentArray.map(async(file) => {
  ....
  // you dont need this line, you can simply return the desiredObj
  // icsFileData.push(desiredObj);
  return desiredObj;
});
// this does the magic, since, icsFileData is a array of Promise
const icsFileDataArray = await Promise.all(icsFileData);
console.log('result: ', icsFileDataArray);
```